# Does any constant raised to the power of iπ equal -1?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm familiar with the interpretation of $e^{i\pi} = -1$ representing a vector of modulus $1$ undergoing a $180$° rotation about the origin in the complex plane, but would this be true for any value raised to the power of $0+i\pi$?

At first I would assume this to be true, but out of curiosity I plugged $\pi^{i\pi}$ into Wolfram Alpha and it gave me a completely different result $(\cos(\pi \ln(\pi)) + i \sin(\pi \ln(\pi)))$ and now I'm curious as to how, exactly, one would go about getting such a result from evaluating $\pi^{iπ}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$z^w=e^{w\log z}\implies \pi^{i\pi}=e^{i\pi\ln\pi}=\cos(\pi\ln\pi)+i\sin(\pi\ln\pi)$$.

Note that $z^w$ is not globally defined,  because we are working with a branch of log.

Comment: You might advise that the expression $z^w$ is not always well-defined unless some restrictions are placed, eg. real $z \gt 0$ (logarithms of complex numbers are multi-valued).

Comment: I took your advice;  I was thinking about doing it anyway.   Now there's the outside chance of $2$ upvotes.  @hardmath

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what interpretation you're talking about.

It is true that when you multiply a complex number $c$ by $e^{i \theta}$, c gets rotated by $\theta$ anti-clockwise on the complex plane, but it is about multiplying by $e^{i \theta}$, and not raising some number to the power $i \theta$.

That is because every complex number $c = a+ib$ can be written as $re^{i \theta}$

Answer (score 0):

Even for real values $a^{i\pi}$ is not in general $-1$. Consider $a=e^2$. Then $a^{i\pi}=e^{2i\pi}=1$.